# Добавление в текущую URL-строку из action формы

Tags: php, url, form, action

К примеру текущий url у меня такой:

```
view_cat.php?category=1015
```

Есть форма:

```
<form method="GET" action="view_cat.php?category=1015">
```

Но после ее обработки получается url:

```
view_cat.php?start_price=4499&end_price=4550&brand%5B%5D=DEXP&submit=
```

Реально ли сделать так, чтобы получилось следующее:

```
view_cat.php?category=1015&start_price=4499&end_price=4550&brand%5B%5D=DEXP&submit=
```

Comment: сделайте hidden  input  c category=1015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте, это можно сделать, добавив в форму с помощью скрипта скрытые поля ввода. Этот код нужно написать внутри вывода формы:

```
foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v) {
  printf("<input type='hidden' name='%s' value='%s' />", $k, $v);
}
```

Он создаст скрытые поля с значениями из url. Если у вас параметры запроса  могут принимать специфические значения (с кавычками и другими специальными символами), то лучше экранировать переменные $k и $v.